# Java nio WatchService for multiple directories

Tags: java, nio, java-7

I want to watch (monitor) multiple directories using Java NIO  [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).
My problem here is the number of directories to watch is dynamic and the user can add any number of directories to the `WatchService`. Is this achievable?

Comment: Yes, it is achievable.

Comment: @Sanchit Thanks for your answer. Can you please guide me how to achieve this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to register multiple paths with the same `WatchService`. Each path gets its own `WatchKey`. The `take()` or `poll()` will then return the `WatchKey` corresponding to the path that was modified.

See [Java's WatchDir example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Following the same link as in previous answers: [Oracle WatchDir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java).

You can create first the `WatchService`:

```
WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
```

At this point you can add many paths to the same `WatchService`:

```
Path path1 = Paths.get("full\path\1\\");
path1.register(watchService,
               StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

Path path2 = Paths.get("full\path\2\\");
path2.register(watchService,
               StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
```

Then you can manage the events as follow:

```
WatchKey key;
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        System.out.println(
          "Event kind:" + event.kind() 
            + ". File affected: " + event.context() + ".");
    }
    key.reset();
}
```

---

Now, if you want to get more information about where was raised the event, you can create a map to link the key and the path by example (You can consider create the variable as class level following your needs):

```
Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
```

In this example you can have the paths inside a list, then you need to loop into it and add each path to the same `WatchService`:

```
for (Path path : paths) {
    WatchKey key = path.register(
            watchService,
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
    keys.put(key, path);
}
```

Now to manage the events, you can add something like it:

```
WatchKey key;
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
    Path path = keys.get(key);
    // More code here.
    key.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just trying to explain how exactly this can be done using `WatchService`.

Here is a piece of code that illustrates how you can use one `WatchService` instance and listen to two `Paths`

```
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<>();

        Path plugins = Paths.get(INSTANCE.getPluginPath());
        logger.info(String.format("Scanning %s ...", plugins));
        registerAll(plugins);

        Path drivers = Paths.get(INSTANCE.getDriverPath());
        logger.info(String.format("Scanning %s ...", drivers));
        registerAll(drivers);
```

The example is based on [Oracle Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java)

Answer (score 0):

adding a complete simple solution for a few fixed directories.   This example has 3 directories that will be monitored and when a file is created i am looking for, i will process it.  Using this approach in Linux instead of a port listener which i need root access.

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class WatchDirSimple {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            
            WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Map<WatchKey,Path> keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
            
            WatchDirSimple watchDirSimple = new WatchDirSimple();
            
            WatchKey key;
            Path dir;
            
            dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator + "Documents\\PROD_Data\\ODBI");
            key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            keys.put(key, dir);
            dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator + "Documents\\PROD_Data\\ODBI\\@fred");
            key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            keys.put(key, dir);
            dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator + "Documents\\PROD_Data\\ODBI\\CMODupgrade");
            key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
            keys.put(key, dir);
            
            for (;;) {

                try {
                    key = watcher.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                    return;
                }

                dir = keys.get(key);
                if (dir == null) {
                    System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                    continue;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                    // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
                    Path name = ev.context();
                    Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                    // print out event
                    System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
                }

                // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
                boolean valid = key.reset();
                if (!valid) {
                    keys.remove(key);

                    // all directories are inaccessible
                    if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            watchDirSimple.register(dir, watcher, keys);
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```