# How many directories can Java WatchService listen to at the same time?

Tags: java, watchservice

Is this OS related, or there is some limitation in Java that I should be aware of?

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Comment: Try looking at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517581/java-nio-watchservice-for-multiple-directories

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535768/what-is-a-reasonable-amount-of-inotify-watches-with-linux)